# Do an action if a button is pressed for a select amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

I'm making a little game for myself, and I want a void to fire for every 0.1 seconds that the `UIButton` is pressed down (e.g., if the button is pressed for 0.7 seconds, the void will fire 7 times within that timeframe).

Is this possisble with a UIButton or do I need to create subviews that will detect a touch? If I use a subview, how do I make the method fire for every 0.1 seconds that the `UIButton` is pressed for?

Comment: ^do the code within the void ([self DoVoid];)

Comment: you mean method to fire/call

Comment: yes, i want the method to call every 0.1 seconds that the UIButton is held down for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a selector for `UIControlEventTouchDown` that starts an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) ticking at a 0.1 second interval and then stop it on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and/or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.  If you are concerned about stopping it while the user's finger is not over the control, you can hook up a cancel event to `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` as well.

The `UIControl` method to use is [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a).  Note that the last argument is a bitmask, so you can hook up all the cancel/stop scenarios in one line of code.